# wordpress website shows "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page"

Tags: wordpress

I already tried with renaming plugins setting default theme, restoring to previous date but nothing works. Please help

Comment: Is this every page of your website? Or only certain pages?

Comment: it is when i try to access the admin area i,e dashboard, front end works fine

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes for this, the following article does a good job addressing several of them: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/sorry-you-are-not-allowed-to-access-this-page-error-in-wordpress/

In my experience if I receive this error it's usually `.htaccess` related and can be solved by first **backing up your current `.htaccess` file** and replacing it with a newly created one with the following contents:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```